# sorting query result is too slow

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-order-by

I have a problem with a big table in a database of an RoR application.

`TABLE EVENTS`:

```
create_table "events", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "id"
    t.integer  "device_id"
    t.string   "data_type"
    t.integer  "element_id"
    t.t.datetime "created_at"
end
```

The problem is when I want to find a record in this table by this query:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE `events`.* FROM `events`
WHERE `events`.`device_id` = N AND `events`.`data_type` = 'S'
AND (`events`.`created_at` BETWEEN 'S' AND 'S')
ORDER BY events.created_at DESC LIMIT 1
```

I want to take the last event in a day, so order the records by `created_at` and pick up the first element.

Unfortunely the operation of sorting costs too much then the query is too slow.

MySQL must do an extra pass to find out how to retrieve the rows in sorted order.

```
Sorting result  7.1760s 7.2565s 1176    8080    0   0
```

Comment: Have you got an index on `events.created_at`?

Comment: What indexes do you have? Indexes will help sorting costs, but you need to consider both the order you want, and the filters you are applying in the WHERE clause.  `(device_id, data_type, created_at DESC)` would be a good index here, but *very* focused on this query.

Comment: i've the solution.....
i need to modify the query and make che time window to short!

Comment: but it's very useful to make index

Answer (score 0):

You could maintain a summary table of your events where you can get the data from perhaps? Populate it using triggers to populate the summary table. The EVENT_SUMMARY table would just contain the latest row or a pointer to the latest row so you would not need to do a sort by in the query at all. I have had this working quite well on a table with about 80 million rows and it worked well.

Things to consider though are that the trigger will cause performance issues on the insert as it is doing extra work.

Depening on how many disaggregators there are the summary table might not be the best approach.

How much data is in there? How often does it get written to (per disaggregator)?